# Printing a pointer with <iostream>

Tags: c++, iostream

Why does

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  cout << (char*)0x10 << endl; 
}
```

segfault, but

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  cout << (void*)0x10 << endl; 
}
```

seems to work just fine?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because

```
cout::operator <<(void*)
```

prints a memory address, and

```
cout::operator <<(char*)
```

prints a null-terminated character array, and you run into undefined behaviour when you attempt to read the `char` array from `0x10`.

Answer (score 4):

The [`ostream::operator<<`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) is overloaded, there is a [version for `char*`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) which interprets the given pointer as a null-terminated string.

Answer (score 3):

There's a special overload for `<<` with `char*`, so that C-style strings can be output easily.

Thus

```
cout << (char*)0x10 << endl;
```

tries to print out the string located at `(char*)0x10` which is not memory it's supposed to look at.